# mouse in opencv

Tags: opencv

I need to compare two images together if any change happened mouse point to it 
how to use mouse in opencv using **visual c++**
but I can't understnd the function can any one simplefied it to me
thnx

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Please use punctuation.

Answer (score 2):

there is an sample called "LK demo" in opencv\samples

in that sample there is **cvSetMouseCallback** calls **on_mouse** function

i think it will be a good start for you